# Continuous Deployment of Nodejs App on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm new at NodeJs development, i'm trying to deploy my App on Azure but i'm facing some problems.
[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXHGy.png)

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE \\.\pipe\5799b955-24fe-43fb-abe5-344be4ce5640
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1376:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:95:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.4.7\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.15.8\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! NodejsWebApp1@0.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the NodejsWebApp1@0.0.0 start script 'node app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the NodejsWebApp1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs NodejsWebApp1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls NodejsWebApp1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?
Thank You

Comment: What does the `app.js` line `95` do?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of error messages. Include any relevant code, stack traces, etc. in your post.

Comment: @FelixFong Line 95 Starts the server listening for connections:
serve.listen(app.get('port'),function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port '+ app.get('port'));
})

Comment: Can you try something like this http://jsbin.com/rafilunuku/edit?js , and have you forgot to get the express port variable with the `app.set` function?

Comment: @FelixFong Yes i have called the `app.set` function. Every thing works fine locally, the problems occurs when i deploy the app on Azure.

Comment: @avojak Sorry, i just corrected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `process.env.PORT` for handling the named pipe port in Azure App Service, see [Listen additional port Microsoft Azure Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424405/listen-additional-port-microsoft-azure-nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs) , the problem is your app are listen to a prot that already exist, and I suggest you to changing your port

Comment: Yes i think that is the problem is related to the port.
I tried several ports but the problem still persists