# Customizing Azure's npm deployment script

Tags: node.js, azure

Azure expects by default a `start` script with the format of `node path/to/js/file`.

Neither of those things fit my setup. I have a 'start:production' script which is comprised of a series of commands joined by `&&`.

For example:

```
"start:production": "npm run build && serve -s -p 3000 dist && npm run --prefix server start",
"build": "node build/build.js",
```

How can one customize default Azure scripts? I saw you can somehow download and edit the default configuration scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Azure Web App which runs on Microsoft IIS. If so, you have no need to config the `start` script in the `package.json` file, instead, add a `web.config` to `/wwwroot` directory and config the entrance file of your node.js app there. Default `web.config` used for node.js apps could be found [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps).

And your app can't listen on port 3000 on Azure Web App, you should use `process.env.PORT` for handling the named pipe port in Azure Web App, see [Listen additional port Microsoft Azure Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424405/listen-additional-port-microsoft-azure-nodejs).

If you want to execute some build scripts after deploying the node.js app you can either use [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) or add `postinstall` script into `package.json` like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
}
```

Comment: Do I have the alternate of a different os / webserver ? I don't have a wwwroot or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, there is an option to choose between Windows or Linux when you create a Web App in the Azure portal.

Comment: And then things will be different?

Comment: Azure Web App on Linux that host Node.js applications using PM2. Which platform are you using?

Comment: Now, nothing. I managed to deploy to heroku. I have a node express repo and a client / static repo (Vue).

Comment: this is my package.json : https://github.com/gkatsanos/isawyou-client/blob/master/package.json apparently Azure doesnt support Yarn. ( `remote: 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
remote: operable program or batch file.` )

Comment: Here's someone doing it manually: https://github.com/stefangordon/kudu-yarn