# Cant connect azureweb app to node server, resulting in net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, pm2

I am using node.js and react and have deployed to the azure app service,
the startup command is `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa` which works

However when I visit the website and visit a page that needs to load images from a database or perform any http requests, the app can't connect to the node.js server and I get the error:
`https://boobah.azurewebsites.net:8080/requests/therapists net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

The call I make in my code to load the data to the page is this:

```
await axios.get('https://boobah.azurewebsites.net:8080/requests/therapists')
```

which works locally just by changing the domain to localhost and on port 3000.

Can anyone please help me for why this is not loading any data to the deployed azure app ?

Thanks you

Comment: Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424405/listen-additional-port-microsoft-azure-nodejs)

Comment: hey @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I also tried this, with 
await axios.get(`https://boobah.azurewebsites.net:${process.env.PORT}/requests/therapists`)

But the data still doesn't load.

In the console i get:

index.js:52 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')